# Division by zero error in php

Tags: php

This line is causing this error:

```
floatval(($sumResult[0]/$total)*100);
```

which throws:

> Warning: Division by zero in /testfile.php on line 44

How can I get this error not to be displayed?

Comment: `$total` is equal to `0` so how do you assign it? (Show some more code)

Comment: *"How can I get this error not to be displayed?"* By fixing the code.

Comment: *"How can I get this error not to be displayed?"* - Turn error reporting off, or fix the real issue. The question would really need to be *"How do I fix this so that it runs properly?"*

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($total<>0) {
     floatval(($sumResult[0]/$total)*100);
} else {
     # what do you want to do if total=0?
}
```

Comment: Ah, the `<>` operator... nice to see you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($total != 0){
floatval(($sumResult[0]/$total)*100);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Division by zero is not possible.
So use this code:

```
if($total) {
   floatval(($sumResult[0]/$total)*100);  
}
else {
   // do not divide
}
```